# ASP.NET Windows authorization for visibility of GridView

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I have implemented windows authentication/authorization but I have to control the visibility of the GridView on the page as well for specific users.

How can I control this, Is there anyway we can maintain list of users(Domainname\username) in our web.config file and check through this list and give visibility of the GridView.

Note: I'm only allow to use web.config file and not allow to make use of local DB or any other XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to control visibility of particular control on the page built in ASP Membership Provider. 
You can set access for particular pages (file locations) for users and/or roles.

To achieve what you want create appSetting in web.config and set value to be comma separated list of users who can see the grid:

```
<add key="UsersWhoCanSeeGrid" value="user1,user2,user3"/>
```

Then on page load retrieve that value by key:

```
string users = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UsersWhoCanSeeGrid"];
```

And check if currently logged user is there:

```
bool showGrid = users.Split(",").Contains(User.Identity.Name);
```

then set Visible property of grid to be 'showGrid'